# How to right the path in app.get function on rest api when my sql query has to select by two elements from the table?

Tags: sql, node.js, rest, api, kotlin

i'am very new in android apps developping, 
I am trying to do an authentification on my app using rest api but i could'nt wright the right path on my function  "app.get"

```
app.get('/getPatient2/:id_patient/',function(req,res){ 
var query = "select * from Patient where id_patient = " + req.params.id_patient ; 
connection.query(query,function(error,results){
if (error) throw error;
res.send(results);
})
});
```

Well, when i test on my browser using the path :

> http://localhost:8082/getPatient2/1

it shows the results normally but that's not what i need in the authetification, it shoud be by phone number and passsword which means :

```
app.get('/xxxxx',function(req,res){ 
var query = "select * from Patient where phone_patient =" + req.params.tel + "and paasword=" + 
req.params.pass; 
connection.query(query,function(error,results){
if (error) throw error;
res.send(results);
})
});
```

i tried many pathes but i get always an error , i searched a lot for documentation but i didn't find any example having a query with "and"

I really hope that you can help me
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path should provide these 2 params, for instance any of these should work:

```
/get-patient/:tel/:pass
/get-patient/tel/:tel/pass/:pass
```

Also, you have a typo in your SQL query: `paasword`.

On a side note, consider having at least HTTPS to pass the password over the network, and use your DB connection library's parameterized queries capabilities. Also, ensure you hash the password in the DB.

Comment: i tried the two of them but it's not working :

app.get('/getPatient/:tel/:pass',function(req,res){ 
    var query = "select * from Patient where tel_patient =" + req.params.tel + "and pwd_patient=" + req.params.pass; 
   connection.query(query,function(error,results){
    
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(results);
})
});


http://localhost:8082/getPatient/0541510384/000

Comment: actually it worked i had an error on my query i should use "" and '' between req.params